# Sprites not moving at all when the layer is set to greater than the player's

Tags: python, pygame

One of the problems you may have seen that's similar to this, and that it wasn't blitting. I found out that it's just not moving no matter what.

Player's init code:

```
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):

        self.game = game
        self._layer = 4
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        

        self.x = x * PLAYERSIZEX2
        self.y = y * PLAYERSIZEY2
        self.width = PLAYERSIZEX
        self.height = PLAYERSIZEY

        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0

        self.default_f = self.game.player_img.get_sprite(21, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.default_b = self.game.player_img.get_sprite(21, 21, self.width, self.height)
        self.default_l = self.game.player_img.get_sprite(0, 42, self.width, self.height)
        self.default_r = self.game.player_img.get_sprite(42, 63, self.width, self.height)

        self.facing = 'down'
        self.animation_loop = 0


        self.image = self.game.player_img.get_sprite(17, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (PLAYERSIZEX2, PLAYERSIZEY2))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

        self.window_col_test = False
```

Block's ENTIRE code (this is one that isn't moving):

```
  def __init__(self, game, x, y):
    self.game = game
    self._layer = 5
    self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    
    self.x = x * TILESIZE2
    self.y = y * TILESIZE2
    self.width = TILESIZE3
    self.height = TILESIZE3

    self.image = self.game.env_tileset.get_sprite(2156, 693, self.width, self.height)

    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (TILESIZE2, TILESIZE2))
    self.image.set_colorkey(RED)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.rect.y = self.y
```

This is how it moves into the right position (in the game class, main function):

```
if self.player.rect.center[0] >= 1280 // 2:
    for sprite in self.all_sprites:
        sprite.rect.x -= self.player.rect.center[0] - 1280 // 2
elif self.player.rect.center[0] <= 1280 // 2:
    for sprite in self.all_sprites:
        sprite.rect.x -= self.player.rect.center[0] - 1280 // 2

if self.player.rect.center[1] >= 720 // 2:
    for sprite in self.all_sprites:
        sprite.rect.y -= self.player.rect.center[1] - 720 // 2
elif self.player.rect.center[1] <= 720 // 2:
    for sprite in self.all_sprites:
        sprite.rect.y -= self.player.rect.center[1] - 720 // 2
```

This is the player's update class (movement is updating x/y_change):

```
def update(self):
    if self.game.cutscene == False:
        self.movement()
    else:
        pass
        
    self.animate()

    self.rect.x += self.x_change
    self.collide('x')
    self.rect.y += self.y_change
    self.collide('y')

    self.x_change = 0
    self.y_change = 0
```

This is the class that moves everything it needs to go:

```
class AreaGen():
    def make_house(self):
        for i, row in enumerate(self.room):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                if column == "P":
                    ground(self, j, i)
                    self.player = Player(self, j, i)

                elif column == "X":
                    h_wall(self, j, i)
                elif column == "D":
                    bed_door(self, j, i)
                elif column == "B":
                    barrier(self, j, i)
                elif column == "S":
                    b_door(self, j, i)
                elif column == "L":
                    l_door(self, j, i)
                elif column == "O":
                    o_door(self, j, i)
                elif column == "W":
                    window(self, j, i)
                else:
                    ground(self, j, i)

    def make_overworld(self):
        for i, row in enumerate(self.overworld):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                random_draw = random.randint(1, 3)
                if random_draw == 1:
                    grass(self, j, i)
                if random_draw == 2:
                    g_blank(self, j, i)
                if random_draw == 3:
                    flower(self, j, i)

                if column == "P":
                    self.player = Player(self, j, i)
                

                if column == "O":
                    plr_house_door(self, j, i)
                if column == "X":
                    plr_house_o_wall(self, j, i)
                if column == "B":
                    bush(self, j, i)
                if column == "W":
                    plr_house_window(self, j, i)
                if column == "#":
                    plr_house_o_wall_top(self, j, i)
                if column == "<":
                    plr_house_top_l(self, j, i)
                if column == "-":
                    plr_house_top_m(self, j, i)
                if column == ">":
                    plr_house_top_r(self, j, i)
```

Here is a list Area Gen is getting off of:

```
plr_outside = [
    'P.<>...................................', # P = player, I put it here for testing stuff on top (<, >)
    '.......................................',
    '.......................................',
    '.......................................',
    '................<------->..............',
    '................#W#W#W#W#..............',
    '................XXXXOXXXX..............',
    '................B.......B..............',
    '................B.......B..............',
    '................B.......B..............',
    '................B.......B..............',
    '................BBB...BBB..............',
    '.......................................',
    '.......................................',
    '.......................................',
    '.......................................',
    '.......................................',
    ]
```

(I hope this is enough code to understand what's going on, if not, let me know)

I do not understand why the block isn't moving no matter what, as I've tried a few things with none working

Comment: I didn't notice that, but yes

Comment: There, you should be good now

Comment: Are you sure it's actually being moved?  As a quick test, add a `print()`  to where the sprite is being moved. something like: `print( "Moving "+str( sprite ) + " by " + str( self.player.rect.center[0] - 1280 // 2 ) )` etc.

I think it would help simplify the code to create a `.move( self, dx, dy )` function on the sprite class.  Then calculate the `dx` and `dy` into variables before calling `.move()` *once* on the sprite.  It makes them easy to log-debug as well.

Comment: It's not being moved at all, that's the thing

Comment: I *believe you*, but there's not much code there to debug.  Maybe you could add more code to the question.  I can't see anywhere that `player.rect` is getting updated, because that code is not in the question... but I assumed this bit was OK.  If you don't want to add code, that's OK, but it means we can only guess at the issue.  Maybe `print()` `player.rect.x` and `.y` each iteration, and confirm these are being updated.  *Something* is causing your sprite positions to be not updated, you have to work through the update algorithm bit-by-bit, checking everything.

Comment: I'm suspicious of your `player.x` and `.y`.  I'm thinking maybe you're somehow updating these and not the `player.rect.x` and `player.rect.y`.  Same for the sprites.  The sprite library relies on the `sprite.rect` for collision, and drawing (it wont use `.x`, `.y`).  Using a separate `x` & `y` might be causing you issues - again, *just a guess*.

Comment: I've seen this question before. Did you repeat the question to attract attention?

Comment: @Rabbid76 No, I got the issue wrong on the last one, so I deleted it and put this one up, as it has the correct issue of it not moving instead of it not blitting

Comment: @Kingsley I have the player updating using rect, but I'll look and see if the sprites are
========
UPDATE:
The rect for sprites are being set to `self.x`, which is what it looks for when placing. The way it knows where to go is by using a tile system, where it reads a list, and puts it where it's at on the list.

If you want, I can make a repl for it and send it here if you want to see EVERYTHING

Comment: No. You have repeated the question. You need to edit the original question instead of asking a new question.

Comment: Yes, what @Rabbid76 says is best.   Please edit the existing question to add all the relevant code.

Comment: I had already deleted the last one

Comment: I just added more code, if you need more let me know

Comment: @Kingsley I added this `print(str(sprite) + " X: " + str(sprite.rect.x))` (in the move thing where it centers) and found out that it's moving things based on what layer they're on, starting from 1 going up. It's stopping when it gets to the player (layer 4), which would explain why it's not moving (anything on 4+), but I don't know how to fix this

Comment: I can see `_layer` defined in the sprite classes, but no use of it.  What library are you using for this, something like tmx-tiles?  tiled?

Comment: No extra libraries, just a simple list. The _layer I thought just set the layer on what's shown on top and what's shown on bottom or in between

Comment: Actually let me add some more code that shows people what lists the area gen is getting off of (key won't be provided)

Comment: So how is the movement supposed to work?  Is it something like the player is always centred in the window, and the tile-sprites move around the player ?

Comment: That is exactly it

Comment: Could that be the cause of the problem though?

Comment: @Kingsley you think that could be the problem or no?

Comment: Yeah, I don't really see that in the code.  IF the algorithm is to keep the player centred, and "move the world around them", then the player `x,y` should never change - it should stay in the window-centre tile.  But then the player's `.update()` function *is* changing the player position.  I'm expecting to read code that sees a keypress, and then (if not a collision) moves the map-sprite(s) by the opposite direction (i.e.: player appears to move "north", but this is implemented as the whole map moving "south").

Comment: @Kingsley It moves, but then re-centers the player, moving every block in the process. (At least every block with layers less than 4, as I'm trying to fix lol)

Comment: Moving the player, then shifting everything back sounds counter-productive.  Try writing out your movement algorithm on paper, then double-check that's what is actually happening.  Add a truck-load of `print()` statements all through the code that so you can verify what you *think* is happening with coordinates, etc. is *actually* happening.  That, or use a debugger (less helpful IMHO).

I can't spot the error in the available code.

Comment: ight, I'll try that